# can you run diffrent GPUs in the same pc without them being linked

Tags: graphics-card

I am thinking about re-installing my old graphics card in my pc alongside my new one to do other tasks separate from my main one. One is an Nvidia card and the other is an AMD card. It isn't needed to run a single thing across both but have one doing one task and another doing something completely different on its own.

Is this possible, and if so is there a way to set programs to use a certain GPU if it doesn't have the option built-in it to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to run them side by side in most cases. Windows and Linux don't really care how many GFX cards are in the machine. I have seen Bitcoin miner rigs running 32 cards for computing work. There are even special motherboards for that with lots of extra PCI-e ports.
I have build rigs myself (for 4x4 screen video-walls) running 4 Nvidia Quadro's with 4 DisplayPort outputs each en without using SLI as we needed each of the 16 screens to be individually controllable.

But some combinations just don't work well because the drivers interfere with each other.
E.g. An Nvidia Geforce combined with a Quadro card from a different GPU generation is known to give some weird stability issues even though they are both made by Nvidia.
There are actually usually less problems if they are from different makers, like in your case, as there is less risk of overlapping areas of the drivers.

Whether your software deals well with it is another matter. Many games get really confused if there are 2 GFX cards without a SLI or Crossfire setup.
And if your software doesn't allow binding to a specific card there really isn't any way to force it. This may lead to weird effects like a program running in a window on the Radeon, but using the NVidia for CUDA operations (which may actually be beneficial if the NVidia is a lot faster).

You just have to try it to see it works in your particular case.

Be warned: Your power-supply must be able to feed both cards at the same time. And even if your PSU can deliver the power, if the cards need extra 6-pin or 8-pin power-connecters your PSU may not have enough of those. Heavy duty power-supplies used in gaming rigs usually come with enough connectors for 2 cards, but the average desktop PSU usually doesn't.